# How to reuse FragmentStatePagerAdapter Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, android-memory

Currently using a `ViewPager` with images on each `Fragment`. Whenever I leave this activity and return to the same activity my memory shoots up about 10mb and stays there like i have a memory leak. I am using leak canary and it is not picking anything up on this page. I also used MAT to look at my heap and this is what I got

[image]

I will eventually hit an OOME if I constantly go back and forth between the activity and  another. here is my code for my `ViewPager`

```
public class ControllerFragment extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    List<Fragment> fragments;
    Context context;


    public ControllerFragment(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }


    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }
}
```

I am thinking I need to implement some sort of `onDestroy()` or reusing the `ViewPager` when I go back to the activity??? Thank you for your help and if anything else is needed I will add it.